# Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The "Data Conversion [....]" has a length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 8000

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssms

I am receiving the subject error when trying to Import a CSV-file with a "text stream [DT_TEXT]" column into an existing Table which contains a varchar(max) column. I can import that same file into a new Table without any issues. It is only when trying to get "Import Data" to append to an existing table that I get the error. I go through the exact similar steps (e.g. Advanced section on "Choose a Data Source", "Suggest Types", specifying DataType as text stream [DT_TEXT] and going through the Edit Mapping after specifying the existing Table to import to, etc.). On the "Review Data Type Mapping" screen I double click the subject column to view the conversion details - and it shows that the Source Type is "text stream [DT_TEXT]" and the Destination Type is varchar(max).

It appears strange, that I am left to import additional file(s) into their own new tables - and then perform SQL-statements to insert from one table to the other if I have a need to combine the data.

Can anyone guide me to what I may be missing ?

Thanks.

RESOLUTION:
I have found a resolution to this issue. In my case at least, I went back and selected a different Destination. Instead of ".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer", I selected "SQL Server Native Client 11.0". And this time around I was actually able to import data with a "text stream [DT_TEXT] column and append to an existing table with a varchar(max) column.

Comment: Put the error in your question (that error looks incomplete), and show us the expression where you're performing the conversion (again, in your question).

Comment: Hi, the full error text (didn't fit into the Title field) was the following

Comment: Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[ValuationData]" has a length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 8000.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204016 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Comment: But please refer my update to the issue - I chose a different Destination which solved the problem.